# Deserialize Binary Search Tree from a string

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

Just practicing and noticed that it's easy to serialize (via depth-first-search traversal) a bst and deserialize it back into the tree. But I am having a hard time deserializing it though if the serialization was done via bread-first-search traversal.

For example, given input: 5,2,11,N,3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Looking for output -

```
      5
    /   \
   2     11
  / \    /  \
 N   3  7    19
      / \    / \
     6   8  N   N
    /\  / \
   N  N N N
```

Comment: Which programming language? It is the most important tag you forgot to add. Secondly, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: 3 should have children N N

Answer (score 0):

Remember, this is *binary* tree search, which means each node has only two children, left and right.

(Assuming N stands for Null/no node):
Build up your tree. The first element in your input sequence is the root element, the next two are assigned as the root's left child and then right child. Then using bfs go down your tree. If the child is a N, go to the next child, if the child is a value, then assign the next two values in your input sequence as that node's left and right children. So forth.

example: 
5,2,11,N,3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign 5 as root.

Consider 5 as node -> it is a value, assign children: 
2,11,N,3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N //remaining input after 5 processed 
Assign 2 as left child.
11,N,3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign 11 as right child. 
// finished entire breadth at dept 0

Consider 2 as node -> it is a value, assign children:
N,3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign N as left child.
3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign 3 as right child.

Consider 11 as node -> it is a value, assign children:
7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign 7 as left child.
19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign 19 as right child.
// finished entire breadth on depth 1

Consider N as node -> not a value, continue to next breadth node.
Consider 3 as node -> it is a value, assign children:
N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign N as left child.
N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N
Assign N as right child.

Consider 7 as node -> ... etc.

You build up a tree as you analise your input string, and use breadth first search to reach the next leaf in this build up tree, if it has a valid value, then it gets assign the next two elements in your input string as left and right children.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialise a string that was generated via breadth first traversal, you essentially use the same mechanics. Use a queue on which you put references to where new children should be injected. As you inject a new child node, add two more references on the queue, one for each grand child.

Since a queue is FIFO, the injection of children will happen in breadth first order.

Here is how it would look in Python:

```py
def to_tree(serialised):
    container = [None]
    leaves = [[container, 0]] # put the reference to the root on the queue

    for value in serialised.split(","):
        children, childIndex = leaves.pop(0) # pull from queue
        if value != 'N':
            node = children[childIndex] = {
                "value": value,
                "children": [None, None]
            }
            # append the new 2 child references to the queue
            leaves.append([node["children"], 0])
            leaves.append([node["children"], 1])
        if len(leaves) == 0: # should not happen if input is complete
            break 

    return container[0] # return the root

# Example call
tree = to_tree("5,2,11,N,3,7,19,N,N,6,8,N,N,N,N,N,N")

# Output the result in JSON format
import json
print(json.dumps(tree, indent=2))
```

The output of the above is:

```
{
  "value": "5",
  "children": [
    {
      "value": "2",
      "children": [
        null,
        {
          "value": "3",
          "children": [
            null,
            null
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": "11",
      "children": [
        {
          "value": "7",
          "children": [
            {
              "value": "6",
              "children": [
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": "8",
              "children": [
                null,
                null
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": "19",
          "children": [
            null,
            null
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```